# WebGL Recursion

Tags: recursion, webgl

I am writing a website that calculates geometry using a recursive algorithm and displays that geometry using WebGL. Can WebGL calculate the geometry using recursion? I know shaders can't be recursive, but I don't know if there is still some recursion supported.

Thanks, Istvan.

Comment: JavaScript supports recursion, so it should that WebGL comply well.

Comment: If the depth of recursion is limited, you can implement recursion in shaders using [macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601521/recursion-in-glsl-prohibited/77470186#77470186).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily generate geometry using recursive algorithms in JavaScript.  You would store the generated geometry in an array buffer, and then pass it into WebGL.  WebGL, however, doesn't have any geometry generation capabilities (e.g., geometry shaders, or subdivision surfaces).

Answer (score 0):

With webgl 1.0 you can get output from shader using render target created with help of webgl [renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#5.14.7) and then use canvas's [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to get buffer with values representing your geometry. It's quite time consuming, but possible. Also, recommend to pay attention to the [project](http://openjscad.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the recursion algorithm in JS and passing the result into the variables that are defined in the shaders would work for your problem.