# Recursion in GLSL prohibited?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, raytracing

I ran into this error when trying to write the following recursive call. I have seen a lot of demos of implementations of recursive Ray tracing in GLSL so I assumed that GLSL supported recursion.

Is this not the case?

OpenGL is returning a compile time error message:

```
Error: Function trace(vec3, vec3, vec3, int) has static recursion
```

This is my function definition:

```
vec3 trace(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 illum, int order) 
{       
   float dist;  
   int s_index = getSphereIntersect(origin, direction, dist);   
   //if light hit
   float light_dist = 200;
   for(int k = 0; k < L_COUNT;k++)      
       if(s_intersects(l_center[k], l_radius[k], 
             origin, direction, 
             light_dist)) 
             if(light_dist < dist )             
                 return l_color[k]; //light is pure color  

   if (s_index != -1)
   {
       illum = s_color[s_index];
       for(int j = 0; j < L_COUNT; j++)
       {
           float ambient = 0.68;
           float diffuse = 0.5;
           vec3 poi = view + (direction * dist); 
           vec3 li_disp = normalize( poi - l_center[j]); 
           vec3 poi_norm = s_normal(s_center[s_index], s_radius[s_index], poi); 
            float shade=  dot(li_disp, normalize(poi_norm)); 
            if(shade < 0) shade = 0;
            illum = illum*l_color[j]*ambient + diffuse * shade; 
            //test shadow ray onto objects, if shadow then 0    
            if(order > 0)
                  illum = trace(poi+.0001*poi_norm, poi_norm, illum, order-1); 
        }   
    }   
    else
        illum = vec3(0,0,0);
    return illum; 
}
```

Comment: If you know maximum depth of your recursion you can replace it with a loop and an array served as a stack

Comment: @MrD Yep here small example of it [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I assumed that GLSL supported recursion

No. GLSL doesn't support or better said allow recursive function calls.

> GLSL does not. The GLSL memory model does not allow for recursive function calls. This allows GLSL to execute on hardware that simply doesn't allow for recursion. It allows GLSL to function when there is no ability to write arbitrarily to memory, which is true of most shader hardware (though it is becoming less true with time).
>
> So, no recursion in GLSL. Of any kind.
>
> – *[OpenGL Wiki – Core Language (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Recursion)*

and

> Recursion is not allowed, not even statically. Static recursion is present if the static function-call graph of
>   a program contains cycles. This includes all potential function calls through variables declared as
>   subroutine uniform (described below). It is a compile-time or link-time error if a single compilation unit
>   (shader) contains either static recursion or the potential for recursion through subroutine variables.
>
> – *[GLSL 4.5 Specification, Page 115](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf)*

Comment: Thank you for this info.

Answer (score 1):

Although GLSL doesn't directly support recursion, it can be implemented using macros if the depth of recursion is limited. This is an implementation of a recursive `fibonacci` function with a maximum recursion depth of 5:

```
#define fib(name,name0) \
int name(int n){ \
    if (n <= 1) \
        return n; \
    return name0(n - 1) + name0(n - 2); \
}

//set this variable to "true" if the maximum depth of recursion is exceeded
bool overflow = false;
int fib0(int n)
{
    overflow=true;
    return -1;
}

//the maximum recursion depth is 5
fib(fib1,fib0)
fib(fib2,fib1)
fib(fib3,fib2)
fib(fib4,fib3)
fib(fib5,fib4)
fib(fibonacci,fib5)
```

The macro is expanded into these functions:

```
bool overflow = false;
int fib0(int n)
{
    overflow=true;
    return -1;
}

int fib1(int n){ if (n <= 1) return n; return fib0(n - 1) + fib0(n - 2); }
int fib2(int n){ if (n <= 1) return n; return fib1(n - 1) + fib1(n - 2); }
int fib3(int n){ if (n <= 1) return n; return fib2(n - 1) + fib2(n - 2); }
int fib4(int n){ if (n <= 1) return n; return fib3(n - 1) + fib3(n - 2); }
int fib5(int n){ if (n <= 1) return n; return fib4(n - 1) + fib4(n - 2); }
int fibonacci(int n){ if (n <= 1) return n; return fib5(n - 1) + fib5(n - 2); }
```

Alternatively, it could be implemented like this:

```
#define recursive(s1) struct s1{int s_;};
recursive(s0)

bool overflow = false;
int fib(int n, s0 s_){
    overflow=true;
    return -1;
}


#define fib_(name,name1) \
recursive(name1) \
int fib(int n,name1 s_){ \
    if (n <= 1) \
        return n; \
    return fib(n - 1,name(0)) + fib(n - 2,name(0)); \
} \

fib_(s0,s1)
fib_(s1,s2)
fib_(s2,s3)
fib_(s3,s4)
fib_(s3,s5)

int fibonacci(int n){
    return fib(n,s5(0));
}
```

You can also define "recursive" data structures using macros, like this binary tree:

```
#define tree(name,name0) \
struct name \
{ \
 int data; \
 name0 left; \
 name0 right; \
}; \
name Tree(int data, name0 left, name0 right){ \
    return name(data,left,right); \
}

//base case
struct tree0
{
 int data;
};
tree0 Tree(int data){
    return tree0(data);
}

tree(tree1,tree0)
tree(tree2,tree1)
tree(tree3,tree2)

int demo(){
    tree2 tree = Tree(1,Tree(1,Tree(1),Tree(2)),Tree(1,Tree(1),Tree(2)));
    return tree.left.left.data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my [old question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/161959/solving-a-recursive-problem-in-the-geometry-or-any-other-shader/161970?noredirect=1#comment379703_161970); yes, I've since realised this is best done using limited-depth loop unrolling. This is also particularly easy to do in JS/WebGPU at runtime, using string replacement functions and language features ([string template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) instead of C macros, to generate several versions of the same shader template.