# Why does Metal compile this recursive function?

Tags: gpu, metal

The Metal spec says that recursive functions are not allowed. However this compiles fine:

```
int b(int c) {
  if (c == 1)
    return b(c++);
  else if (c == 2)
    return b(c + 2);
  else
    return c;
}
```

Why is that? What is the definition of recursive that Metal is using? It refers to section 5.2.2 of the C++14 spec, which also does not give any definition of "recursive" thus I'd expect the above to be a standard example of recursion.

Even if I do this, it still compiles:

```
int b(int c) {
    return b(c + 2);
}
```

What gives?!

Comment: What happens if you try to compile a non-tail recursive function?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If I were you, I'd follow up with Apple directly to see if you can find out what's going on. You should also specify the exact version of the metal compiler (transpiler?) you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can compile fine like any C++ function, no problem. It's when you *call* the function from a kernel that you will get a compile error about recursive function use.

Comment: In shading languages that don't allow recursive functions, I usually implement recursion by macro expansion. This is possible [in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77470186/975097), and probably in Metal as well.